# Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-7

I am downloading a xml file from the internet and save it in isolated storage. If I try to read it I get an error:

> Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.

```
string tempUrl = "http://xxxxx.myfile.xml"; // changed
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(tempUrl));
client.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(delegate(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e) {

StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(new IsolatedStorageFileStream("myfile.xml", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, myIsolatedStorage));
 writer.WriteLine(e.Result);
 writer.Close();
});
```

This is how I download and save the file...

And I try to read it like that:

```
IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = myIsolatedStorage.OpenFile("myfile.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(fileStream);
```

This is where I get the error...

I have no problem reading the same file without downloading and saving it to isolated storage... so there must be the fault.

Comment: What do you mean by what does the content look like? It's a typical xml file. I have no problem reading the same file without downloading and saving it to isolated storage... so there must be the fault.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the contents *of the file*. I strongly suspect *that* won't be a typical XML file...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This:

```
writer.WriteLine(e.Result);
```

doesn't do what you think it does. It's just calling `ToString()` on a `Stream`, and writing the result to a file.

I suggest you avoid using a `StreamWriter` completely, and simply copy from `e.Result` straight to the `IsolatedStorageFileStream`:

```
using (var output = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("myfile.xml", FileMode.Create, 
                                    FileAccess.Write, myIsolatedStorage))
{
    CopyStream(e.Result, output);
}
```

where `CopyStream` would be a method to just copy the data, e.g.

```
public static void CopyStream(Stream input, Stream output)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[8 * 1024];
    int read;
    while((read = input.Read (buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    {
        output.Write (buffer, 0, read);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for educating me so kindly. I found out also that the content of the file was "MS.Internal.InternalMemoryStream" instead of xml content I expected. I had to install separate plugin to check isolated storage so that's why it took time. Your suggestions work perfectly!!!